# INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat7, java-6, eclipse-mars

I have below the Tomcat error log.  I've checked and there are no duplicate or multiple instances of the server running.  Also, I've checked server.xml and adjusted to a different port from 8080 to 8000 but it doesn't fix the issue.

Appreciate your time!

MD5 (eclipse-jee-mars-2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz) = 0ce714791de23c93e5488d9b22fdf73c

MD5 (apache-tomcat-7.0.105.tar.gz) = 10c216854a3171cca1d0ddf11fd7b002

MD5 (mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.tar.gz) = ab9ac454a959859a297b53bdbf156f3c

```
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/7.0.105
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 2 2020 12:25:26 UTC
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 7.0.105.0
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.15.5
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_261-b12
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/jchen/Softwares/BlizzardOfBucksMachine/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/jchen/Softwares/Apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.105
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/jchen/Softwares/BlizzardOfBucksMachine/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/jchen/Softwares/Apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.105
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/jchen/Softwares/BlizzardOfBucksMachine/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/jchen/Softwares/Apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.105/endorsed
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/jchen/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 981 ms
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.105
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/Users/jchen/Softwares/BlizzardOfBucksMachine/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleProject/WEB-INF/lib/el-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/Users/jchen/Softwares/BlizzardOfBucksMachine/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleProject/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleProject]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [org_apache_tomcat_websocket] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2338)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5536)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 6 more

Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleProject]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [org_apache_tomcat_websocket] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2338)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5536)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 6 more

Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleProject]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [org_apache_tomcat_websocket] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2338)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:888)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5536)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 6 more

Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Comment: Sep 14, 2020 7:42:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleProject]]                                                                        
 This line drew my eyes.  This concurrent is this new?  Why is it using Microsoft naming convention?

Comment: Looking through the  severe issues.  It looks like it's referring to all within catalina.jar within lib directory.  This was working once upon the time but this part is failing to start.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give same path in web.xml file and servlet like in servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/don't put same name")
```

and in your `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <URL-pattern>/here don't put same path</URL-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Go with either one of them.